# google-app-engine not running projects windows 7

Tags: google-app-engine

Hello i have a problem with google app engine. i have installed python 2.7.4 from python.org and i also installed google app engine for python fro google's site. Then i create a new project, i load it, click on the run button. so far so good. then it stop doing anything and the little icon next to the name is yellow clock. if i click run again it says "cannot run check preferences or install python"

I checked in the cmd and python is already installed. In the preferences i have clicked both the "c/python27/python.exe and c/python27/pythonw.exe" but still no solution.

is there any way i can make it work?

Comment: just installed in my mothers laptop. windows 7 also. the same thing exactly. so i think it is a matter of conflict between the two programms.